# using a modal, click one element to trigger another element

Tags: jquery, click, parent-child

I am pretty new to JQuery, coding isn't my strong suit but i gotta learn somehow, anyways my problem is I want to click on a parent element that will start a function to click a child element. that part of my code works

```
jQuery('.div_image').click(function() {

jQuery(this).find('.gallory_image').click();

{);
```

the next part I am having trouble with is that when .gallory image is clicked it triggers a popup that shows the image from the element clicked. the popup shows up, but its a blank back ground the code im using is this

```
var image = jQuery(this).attr('src');   
 
jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-image' , 'url(' + image + ')');

jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-size', 'contain');


jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');

jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-position' , 'center');
```

when I change the code so I can click on the child itself it works fine, but when I try to trigger .gallory_image by clicking on the parent .div_image it brings up the blank background. I have scoured the Internet for weeks, and anything I try just doesn't work. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fidakhattak I was having some issues with your code so I spent a couple of hours playing with it,

the problem with your code I was having is the pop up placement, and the src still was not showing the image. it would pop up at top of the page instead of (center, center) of browser when I clicked on the element. I fixed the src image by creating two separate functions the first of your code

```
jQuery('.div_image').click( function() {

var child = jQuery(this).find('.gallory_image');
child.click();
```

and the second finding the source,

```
jQuery('.gallory_image').click( function() {

var image = jQuery(this).attr('src');
```

and that worked, the image appeared!, but the popup was still forced to top of page. easily solution i tried just to see if it would work was make the popup trigger be .div_image instead of .gallory_image and get rid of child.click();

so my code looks like this.

```
jQuery('.div_image').click( function() {

var child = jQuery(this).find('.gallory_image');  

var image = child.attr('src');

jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-image' , 'url(' + image + ')');
jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-size', 'contain');
jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
jQuery('.lightbox-popup').css('background-position' , 'center');
});
```

Boom! finally got this fixed! ugh been on this for a couple of months couldn't have done it with out you!